# Will there be any change in the fringe pattern with temperature in case of crystal diffraction?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, diffraction

When i carry out crystal diffraction when the crystal is at high temperature or low teperature , will there be any change in the fringe pattern?

Comment: This is a key component of the Simmons-Balluffi experiment to determine point defect concentrations in crystals - you measure the overall length change of the crystal and the changes in lattice spacings to back out the vacancy concentration.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely.

If the crystal undergoes thermal expansion, the spacing between crystal planes will change and this will affect the fringe spacing. If the crystal undergoes a phase transition (to a different crystal system - like diamond (cubic) vs graphite (hexagonal)), the pattern will change even more drastically. Even without a phase transition, it is possible that heating would anneal a polycrystalline structure so you end up with a different diffraction pattern.